# What is the minimum safe gap berween leads on a 240 volt oven bake element?

Tags: electrical, oven

I am replacing the bake element in my oven.

The old element has a  minimum gap of about 1 3/8 inches between the leads. The gap between the leads in the replacement element is about 9/16 inch.
Is this sufficient space between the leads?

Comment: What make and model is the oven, and is the replacement element an OEM part or a "universal" service replacement?

Comment: The oven is Hotpoint Model RK6380012BO.  The the old element, WB44X5082, is not the original oven part.  The replacement element is Exact Replacements Range Oven Element ERB 44X5082

Answer (score 1):

I would double check this element, is it possible you received one that's mislabelled?

I haven't worked on a stove in a long time but I was under the impression that the distance between terminals was a critical dimension for a part to fit properly.

The amazon page for the replacement part shows the distance for that part as 1-1/4" which pretty much agrees with your measurement.

[Amazon - ERB44X5082](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0047SJCQE)

[image: ERB44X5082]

And looking at a GE replacement part on Amazon, that looks like about 1-1/4" too...

[Amazon - GE WB44X5082 Bake Element](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003BIGD40)

[image: WB44X5082]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ThreePhaseEal. The reason we are asking is that if it is an approved replacement. The liability falls to the manufacturer and that would not be a concern for an electrician. Since the manufacturer has an entire engineering staff to figure those things out.

Other than that there is no NEC requirement, but NFPA 70E "The National Electric **Safety** Code" does address it.

> As there is no US definition of finger safe, manufacturers and AHJs have been using IEC-60529, the international Ingress Protection standard, or IP Code, as a basis for determining if a part is suitably guarded, isolated, or insulated for the porposes of NFPA 70E. This standard holds that an assembly is considered finger-safe (IP-2X compliant) if a 12.5 mm (1/2 inch) metal sphere probe 80 mm in length (the size of an average little finger) is unable to make contact with any potentially energized circuit component within the assembly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My use of the word "safe" was not the best word to characterize my concern.  My concern is the potential for fire from arcing between the leads.

Comment: As far as arcing you could cut the distance to 1/3 and it would still be fine.

Comment: @Paul The bake element is not conductive so arcing or shock risk is not a worry. Only at the plugin connection  can you see exposed metal. Those will be completely covered when inserted into the oven and secured with the retaining plate and screws